# REGEX matching (1|2) while NOT containing (3|4)

Tags: regex, preg-match

I know I have just asked a similar question earlier today, but seeing as how easily it appeared to be solved it's given me the thought that something a little more complex might be acheivable! I have strings with "regions" in brackets. I want to match all strings with, for example `Japan` or `Brazil` BUT not if they contain, for example `USA`, `Europe` or `UK`. Because they are are all preceded by either `(` or a space and followed by either `,` or `)` it makes it tricky!

At the moment I'm having to do two seperate matches to match `Japan` or `Brazil` and then make sure I'm not matching `USA`, `Europe` or `UK`.

Inputs:

```
MatchMe! (Japan)
MatchMe! (Japan, Brazil)
MatchMe! (Brazil, Japan)
MatchMe! (Other, Japan, Other)
Don'tMatchMe! (Japan, USA)
Don'tMatchMe! (USA, Japan)
Don'tMatchMe! (Brazil, USA, Japan)
Don'tMatchMe! (USA)
```

Regex I'm using now:

```
\(.*?, Japan\)|\(Japan, .*?\)|\(.*?, Japan, .*?\)|\(.*?Japan.*?\)
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/h17uZ2/1

Answer (score 2):

Combine positive lookahead for non-parentheses characters followed by `Japan|Brazil` with a negative lookahead for the same, but with `USA|Europe|UK` instead:

```
\((?=[^)]*(Japan|Brazil))(?![^)]*(USA|Europe|UK))[^)]+\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/h17uZ2/2

Comment: Thanks, this blows my mind - I struggle with this logicaly orientated stuff :D - I'm able to use this format to condense some of my other preg_matches as well, so thankyou!